# Partly editing inline style attribute of an element

Tags: javascript, html, css, attributes

It's currently working like such:

```
var ball = document.getElementById('ball');
//some code
let bml = parseInt(ball.style.marginLeft,10);
//if *conditional statement* is true, do:
ball.setAttribute("style","margin-left:"+(bml-4)+"px;");
```

But I'm trying to achieve it by writing this:

```
ball.style['marginLeft']=bml-4;
```

except the result isn't the same.

I've seen online examples of using this method to edit attribute values dynamically but they always seemed to use pre-calculated values like "400px" and never variables like my example, why is that?

Comment: I think you're missing the css unit. It should be `ball.style["marginLeft"] = bml-4 + "px"`.

Comment: You're right, I actually had tried this solution before but it didn't work because I was adding it like "px;"..
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Style properties must be set with string values, as it is documented in the following link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style#setting_styles

So it is possible to dynamically set style values by using String Literals:

```
ball.style['marginLeft']=`${bml-4}px`;
```

Comment: Yeah, I had tried String(bml-4) but was missing "px" 
Also it worked simply by concatenating: bml-4+"px"